# C# windows application, image file from resource folder gets removed, getting error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

In C#.net windows application, by mistake i have deleted an image from the resource folder, from solution explorer. Now its showing

Link: http://postimg.org/image/9rebh6e49/

> 109 errors in the resource file properties.
>
> Error  1   Partial declarations of 'CD_Management.Properties.Resources' have conflicting accessibility modifiers
>
> Error  2   The namespace 'CD_Management.Properties' already contains a definition for 'Resources'

CD_Management is my project name. Is there any method to solve it as i could not even now change the background image or any other image of my forms.

Comment: I think u should regenerate the form Resource2. i think this will resolve your problem.

Comment: You don't mention whether or not you added the image back into the resources folder

Comment: yes when i add new image, this error occurs.

Comment: After restoring those image file back, that also not fixes the problem....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two conflicting classes with the name "Resources", one generated and probably with internal access, and one which was added manually and probably public.
I noticed the name of your file - **Resources2.Designer.cs**, this looks unnatural and modified.
Try to search the solution for all classes with name "Resources" and delete the ambigous one.